# AttributeError: 'LlamaForCausalLM' object has no attribute 'load_adapter'

Tags: huggingface-transformers, large-language-model, llama, peft

I trained a model based on meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf with peft, a quantized model and lora.
Then I saved my model via

```
model.push_to_hub("my-awesome-model")
```

now I can't load the model anymore and it shows the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'LlamaForCausalLM' object has no attribute 'load_adapter'
```

I tried loading it according to the huggingface docs:

```
peft_model_id = "username/my-awesome-model"
model.load_adapter(peft_model_id)
```

and loading the normal model first and then doing

```
peft_model_id = "username/my-awesome-model"
model2 = LlamaForCausalLM.from_pretrained(peft_model_id, device_map="auto", load_in_4bit=True, use_auth_token= hf_auth)
```

which should also work according to the docs, but gave me

```
does not appear to have a file named config.json
```